# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. ​

Tags: python, egg

I am trying to install 'pymote' using pip install pymote, but getting the below error. Please help to rectify this:

```
Collecting pymote
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/3b/7dea254522b625c1ae5fe24154133f71c7a0b5c0c0c7bdbffbd7b0af9b76/Pymote-0.2.2.zip
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\manish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\manish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1kfxd38n\\pymote\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\manish\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1kfxd38n\\pymote\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\manish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1kfxd38n\pymote\pip-egg-info'

cwd: C:\Users\manish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1kfxd38n\pymote\
Complete output (6 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\manish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1kfxd38n\pymote\setup.py", line 11
except ImportError, AttributeError:  # @ReservedAssignment
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Note: I have already upgraded the setuptools

Comment: Did you check the logs for the full command output?